# Como enviar arquivos do aplicativo para a API

Tags: react-native, axios, laravel-5.5

Tenho um APP em **React-native** e uma API com **Laravel**

Os dois estão se comunicando corretamente, envio dados da APP para a API e o contrário corretamente

No momento para enviar e receber as requisições no APP utilizo o **axios**

Porém agora eu gostaria de enviar arquivos e imagens do APP para a API

Consigo obter o endereço da imagem no celular

Mas ai em diante não sei como proceder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### reactive-native upload

Ficaria algo como:

```
const data = new FormData();

data.append('campo_foto_use_no_laravel', {
  uri: photo.uri,
  type: 'image/jpeg', // ou photo.type
  name: 'minhaFoto' // ou photo.name
});

fetch(url, {
  method: 'post',
  body: data
}).then(res => {
  console.log(res)
});
```

### Múltiplas fotos

```
const photos = [photo1, photo2, ...]

photos.forEach((photo) => {
    data.append('photo', {
    uri: photo.uri,
    type: photo.type,
    name: photos.name
  });  
});

fetch(url, opts);
```

Para implementar progresso do upload crie um arquivo chamado `api.js` e adicione isto:

```
const futch = (url, opts={}, onProgress) => {
    console.log(url, opts)
    return new Promise( (res, rej)=>{
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(opts.method || 'get', url);
        for (var k in opts.headers||{})
            xhr.setRequestHeader(k, opts.headers[k]);
        xhr.onload = e => res(e.target);
        xhr.onerror = rej;
        if (xhr.upload && onProgress)
            xhr.upload.onprogress = onProgress; // event.loaded / event.total * 100 ; //event.lengthComputable
        xhr.send(opts.body);
    });
}
export default futch
```

Como usar:

```
import futch from './api'; //Importa o asp.js

const data = new FormData();
data.append('name', 'testName');
data.append('photo', {
  uri: source.uri,
  type: 'image/jpeg',
  name: 'testPhotoName'
});


futch(url, {
  method: 'post',
  body: data
}, (progressEvent) => {
  const progress = progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total;
  console.log(progress); //Exibe o progress
}).then(
  (res) => console.log(res),
  (err) => console.log(err)
)
```

- Fonte: https://github.com/g6ling/React-Native-Tips/tree/master/How_to_upload_photo%2Cfile_in%20react-native

---

### Axios

Agora no Axios, pode fazer assim:

> Note que `document.getElementById('arquivo').files[0]` pega o valor do `<input type="file" name="arquivo" id="arquivo">`

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('file', document.getElementById('arquivo').files[0]);

//Configura a barra de progresso
var config = {
    onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
        var percentCompleted = Math.round( (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total );
        console.log(percentCompleted);
    }
};

axios.put('URI da API', data, config)
    .then(function (res) {
        console.log(res.data); //Resposta HTTP
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err.message); //Erro HTTP
    });
```

- Breve documentação: https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: Vlw mesmo, vou tentar aqui